# Query records in one table that exists in either of two columns in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables. One with user info, one with payment info. I would like to find out users that are either the sender or the receiver of a payment.

Eample data:

user

| id | other columns |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

payments:

| sender | receiver | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 5 |  |

ideal output

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

what I tried:

```
SELECT id
FROM user u
where exists
(
SELECT 1
FROM payments p
where u.id = p.sender or u.id = p.receiver
)
```

BigQuery gave the error:

> LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

which is quite confusing to me

Comment: @forpas however Bigquery refuse to run it

Comment: show us the create table, as the error states that you have different data types between user and payments

Comment: both id in user and sender, receiver in payments are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `WHERE u.id = p.sender or u.id = p.receiver` makes `LEFT SEMI JOIN` to be **non-equi** join.

You can separate **WHERE** condition into 2 **EXITS** clauses.

```sql
SELECT id 
  FROM user u
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM payments p WHERE u.id = p.sender) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM payments p WHERE u.id = p.receiver)
;
```

output:

[image]

But this approach sometimes shows very poor performance in real circumstances.

So, below query would be another option you can use in that case.

```sql
SELECT id FROM user u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM payments p WHERE u.id = p.sender) 
 UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM user u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM payments p WHERE u.id = p.receiver)
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but should it be union distinct instead?

Comment: Sure, if  **semi join** makes duplication, you need to use `union distinct` instead of `union all`.

Comment: It depends on your data, so kindly check your data and how **join** makes the result set first, then decide which one you will use. (**union distinct** requires additional computing resources and makes your query slow.)

Comment: Yes, thank you. In my case, it does require union distinct.

Answer (score 1):

I think below is the most optimal solution

```
select distinct id
from payments, unnest([sender, receiver]) id
join user
using(id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, you always give me an inspiration. I appreciate that.  One thing I wonder is that your query turn **LEFT SEMI JOIN** problem into **INNER JOIN** problem. As per my understanding, **LEFT SEMI JOIN** is a little bit efficient than **INNER JOIN** in terms of performance, cause in **LEFT SEMI JOIN**, left table  moves to next row when it finds a matching key, whereas in **INNER JOIN** each row in left table scans entire right table to find a matching key.  I may have incorrect information, but if so, I wonder which one you prioritize when code simplicity and performance conflicts.

Comment: glad to be inspiration for you and I hope many others :o) as of JOINs - if this would be tsql - I would might be with you on this. But with BigQuery - I am not sure if I agree. BigQuery engine is quite different. I suggest you to experiment with real-sized data to clarify subject. As of preferences - simplicity vs. performance  - this is really multi-factored - it really depends  - and not just on data size and nature of data, but also on particular user and his/her ability to maintain code - just few factors to mention :o)

Comment: Good point, thanks for your kind explanation.